# Only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars with log

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, scipy

```
from numpy import * 
from pylab import * 
from scipy import * 
from scipy.signal import * 
from scipy.stats import * 


testimg = imread('path')  

hist = hist(testimg.flatten(), 256, range=[0.0,1.0])[0]
hist = hist + 0.000001
prob = hist/sum(hist)


entropia = -1.0*sum(prob*log(prob))#here is error
print 'Entropia: ', entropia
```

I have this code and I do not know what could be the problem, thanks for any help

Comment: It run here. What was the error? Can you add the error output?

Answer (score 4):

This is an example of why you should never use `from module import *`. You lose sight of where functions come from. When you use multiple `from module import *` calls, one module's namespace may clobber another module's namespace. Indeed, based on the error message, that appears to be what is happening here.

Notice that when `log` refers to `numpy.log`, then `-1.0*sum(prob*np.log(prob))` can be computed without error:

```
In [43]: -1.0*sum(prob*np.log(prob))
Out[43]: 4.4058820963782122
```

but when `log` refers to `math.log`, then a TypeError is raised:

```
In [44]: -1.0*sum(prob*math.log(prob))
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

---

The fix is to use explicit module imports and explicit references to functions from the module's namespace:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

testimg = np.random.random((10,10))

hist = plt.hist(testimg.flatten(), 256, range=[0.0,1.0])[0]
hist = hist + 0.000001
prob = hist/sum(hist)

# entropia = -1.0*sum(prob*np.log(prob))
entropia = -1.0*(prob*np.log(prob)).sum()
print 'Entropia: ', entropia
# prints something like:  Entropia:  4.33996609845
```

---

The code you posted does not produce the error, but somewhere in your actual code `log` must be getting bound to `math.log` instead of `numpy.log`. Using `import module` and referencing functions with `module.function` will help you avoid this kind of error in the future.