# TA-Lib Python Wrapper only length-1 arrays error

Tags: python, python-2.7, ta-lib

**Code:**

```
   def macd(prices):
        print "Running MACD"
        prices = np.asarray(prices)
        print prices
        macd, macdsignal, macdhist = MACD(prices, fastperiod=12, slowperiod=26, signalperiod=9)
        print "MACD "+macd
```

**Explanation:**

Im trying to run some analysis on a Python list containing closing prices.

I understand that I must convert the list before handing it over to TA-Lib, since I have seen all examples doing that.

However this is met by a  `only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`

Answer (score 8):

I was importing the talib module like so, just like in [TA-Libs website](https://mrjbq7.github.io/ta-lib/func.html):

```
from talib.abstract import MACD
```

However, this is frowned upon in the community and today I found out why. One modules namespace was clobbering the other modules namespace, leading to the error. This is well put [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34110138/6388893).

So I just imported talib cleanly:

```
import talib
```

The final code that works is:

```
def macd(prices):
        print "Running MACD"
        prices = np.array(prices, dtype=float)
        print prices
        macd, macdsignal, macdhist = talib.MACD(prices, fastperiod=12, slowperiod=26, signalperiod=9)
        print "MACD "+macd
```

Comment: oh boy, I had the same problem.
Maybe they should change their examples, or am I getting something wrong here? :)
you saved my evening..

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. I met the same problem.